# Chroot based on group name

Tags: linux, chroot

I have a *nix system on which I want to get a SFTP chroot configured. Let's say there are three users, users from the same country can read and write the files from their countries, but should be chrooted so that they cannot access the files from other countries:

Firstly, make a chroot:

```
$ sudo su -
$ mkdir /chroot
```

Then create my users, their information is:

```
alice
  group: uk
  other group: sftp-user    

bob
  group: uk
  other group: sftp-user

charlie
  group: italy
  other group: sftp-user
```

Each of them has been created with the command

```
useradd -g <group> -G <other group> -d /chroot/<group> -s /sbin/nologin -m <username>
```

(When `bob` is made, it'll complain about the home directory already existing, that's okay)

Now I *think* I need to add details to the `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file, but all the examples on the web are for user based chroots, not group ones. My plan is:

```
#Subsystem stfp /the/old/sftp/subsystem
Subsystem sftp internal-sftp

Match Group sftp-user
      ForceCommand internal-sftp
      ChrootDirectory %h
```

Does this seem right? I'm not having any luck!

Comment: I tried to use something similar on Enterprise Linux 6, but I had no luck. The OpenSSH from it was probably too old.

Answer (score 1):

Very old question but I'll answer for anyone landing here from Google,

Your **sshd_config** looks fine for sftp only use-cases, your problem is likely caused by something else.

The best place to find out what's wrong is the latest entries in **/var/log/auth.log** after a failed login attempt. It's also worth checking the ssh service is running, if it is not, there's likely a formatting error elsewhere in the sshd_config.

You also need to make sure the home directory (%h) of each user is owned by **root:root** and ensure the user cannot write to it - this is a requirement for the root directory of a jail:

```
drwxr-xr-x 9 root root 4.0K Aug  2 00:10 alice
```

---

If you want to allow both ssh and sftp (chrooting both) use this:

```
Subsystem sftp internal-sftp

Match Group jailed
    ChrootDirectory %h
    AllowTcpForwarding no
    X11Forwarding no
```

Now to make ssh work, you'll need to copy /bin/bash (or whichever is the user's default shell) into the user's home directory:

```
cp /bin/bash $HOME/bin
```

Along with all dependencies into $HOME/lib and $HOME/lib64.

```
DEPS=$(ldd /bin/bash | grep -Po '\/lib(64)?\/[a-zA-Z0-9\-_/.]+.so((.[0-9]{1,2})*.[0-9]{1,2})?' | tr '\n' ' ')
cp -n --parents $DEPS $HOME/
```

These all need to be executable by the user.

This is a minimum, other programs such as ls and cat would need the same treatment.

[Here's a great tutorial on how to setup the chroot jail for ssh users](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/debian-ubuntu-restricting-ssh-user-session-to-a-directory-chrooted-jail/)

Comment: (1) What do you mean by “Your `sshd_config` is fine  …”? The OP says that it isn’t working. (2) Why are you telling the OP that they should prevent their users from writing to their home directories?  Maybe the OP *wants* them to be able to collaborate by sharing files in the sftp server. Are you telling the OP how to implement a requirement that they haven’t stated, or is there some real, good reason why the home directories should be owned by root? (3) According to the question, the default shell of the sftp users is `/sbin/nologin`. Why do you believe the OP wants them to be able to ssh in?

Comment: 1) Because it is correct, the issue OP has is likely caused by something else (unless there’s more to their config file that they have not shown us), as I’ve posted, the best place to find out the issue is in the auth.log. 2) The root owned, user not-writable root of a chroot jail is a requirement of an sftp jail, and here OP has showed the root of the jail is the home dir. 3) Absolutely true, OP didn’t ask for this, but it’s a 6 year old question with no answer and I thought I’d add it to be more helpful as it’s not easy info to find